# How to protect my portable HDD from physical damage?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, maintenance

I have a 1TB Portable HDD - Western Digital: My Passport.
I usually keep it in my pocket and move around a lot, I wanted to know what I can do to protect it from possible damage (if there is any). I try not to move or shake it when it's working and try to use Safe Remove as much as possible.

What are the possible risks of my actions and how can I avoid damaging the drive?

Comment: The portable drive you have is designed to be moved. It is not designed to be dropped. If you don't drop it or unplug it while its transfering files you should  be fine

Comment: Not using Safely Remove Hardware (or the equivalent on other OSes) should never cause hardware problems, although it *may* (very much depending on other settings) cause the file system to become inconsistent.

Comment: Not unmounting on linux may cause problems due to lazy writes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll get many answers which are not pointing out the obvious...

**Dont's**

Don't use it as a football
Don't toast it

**DO**

Do keep it wrapped in foam (but not so much it creates moisture)
Do carry it only within a bomb proof case...

You get the idea! There is no definitive rule for this!

Even if you leave it at home, it can be knocked off, damaged from earthquake/fire etc...

How do you protect your phone? Personally, unless you're going swimming with it, I wouldn't worry too much. These things are designed to be fairly robust and IMO they use the term fairly to keep it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

A good policy will be

1)Don't drop it.

2)Use "safeley remove"/"eject" prior to removing it.